# Django templates: output float with all decimal places

Tags: python, django

how can I output this number in django templates (number of decimal places is variable and I don't know it in advance):

```
x = 0.000015
```

1)

```
{{x}}
```

output is:

```
1,5e-05
```

2)

```
{{x|stringformat:"f"}}
```

output is:

```
0.000015
```

which is not localized, there should be comma! I need output to be localized and keep all decimal places.

I can't believe that django can't handle such a simple task using built-in tools.

UPDATE:
I have correct settings already:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
USE_L10N = True
```

And default Django output works fine for most of float numbers, it only fails on this small number. It outputs with exponent notation, but I need to output as float with all decimal places (number of decimal places is variable).

Answer (score 4):

If you know length of numbers you can try to use floatformat filter:

```
{{ x|floatformat:6 }}
```

where 6 is length of decimal part.

Comment: i updated question - number of decimal places is variable and i don't know it in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That happens due to the wrong locale settings.
Django localization works using the the current locale settings([Format Localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/formatting/)):

> When using Django's formatting system, dates and numbers on templates will be displayed using the format specified for the current locale.

To fix it, you should set the correct locale, I'm assuming it is pt_BR (due to the comma), but you may use it whatever locale it is correct.

try to add this on your settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'
USE_L10N = True
```

and then re-run your code

Comment: I already have these settings (in my case LANGUAGE_CODE='ru'). It works for all other float numbers, but fails only for this small one -  outputs with exponent notation which I do not need.

Comment: Try to set to "ru-RU", which is the valid code for Russian and also verify if it is installed by running `import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8")` on the command line.

Comment: I even tried LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'  and it still outputs as '1,5e-05'

Comment: Try to add `{% load l10n %}` on the top of the template, then use `{{x|stringformat:"f"|localize}}`

Comment: Also, if you know how many decimal places there ir, you may also try: `{{ x|floatformat:6 }}`

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution, which works perfectly fine.

First convert FloatField to DecimalField:

```
some_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=15)
```

and then output in template as follows:

```
{{x.some_value.normalize}}
```

As result it outputs 0.000015 as "0.000015"