# How to format variable in template as currency?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to format a string in a template to display as a currency. `{{ object.cost }}`
Would I be able to do something like `"${:,.2f}".format({{ object.cost }})` in the template?

Comment: Hey, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524339/number-formatting-in-django-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use floatformat filter:

```
{{ object.cost|floatformat:2 }}
```

where 2 means two decimals.

As, [Django templates: output float with all decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950478/django-templates-output-float-with-all-decimal-places)

Comment: Japanese Yen does not have decimals.